# Local notification isn't shown

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I need to show a simple local notification, just to understand how does it work. Fro this purpose I wrote this code:

```
askPermissions = async () => {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    return finalStatus === 'granted';
  };

  sendNotificationImmediately = async () => {
    const notificationId = await Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync({
      title: 'This is header',
      body: 'This is body',
    });
    console.log(notificationId);
  };
```

And called this method in a such way:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.askPermissions()) {
      console.log('Permission presents');
      this.sendNotificationImmediately();
    } else {
      console.log('Denied');
    }
  }
```

To wrote this code I used [this](https://fyndx.io/react/local-notifications-in-expo/) tutorial. But when I run the app notification isn't shown, but permission presents. So, what's the reason of the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
askPermissions = async () => {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
      finalStatus = status;
    } else if (finalStatus === 'granted') {
      Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync({
        title: 'This is header',
        body: 'This is body',
      });
    }

componentDidMount() {
    this.askPermissions();
  }
```

Hope this helps.